# Gulp Browser Sync doesn't work

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I am trying to set up very simple gulp file. I am using sass and browser sync there and I move everything to the build folder. But for unknown reason the browser does not sync. 
I tried solutions from many resources but nothing seem to work so far. Maybe some of you would have any idea how to fix that.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = bs.reload;

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
        .pipe(bs.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('serve', ['styles'], function() {
     bs.init({
            server: "./build"
        });

    gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('build/css/*.css').on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

My folder structure is:
- build
  - css
  - index.html
- sass
- index.html

And the command prompt shows this after running gulp:
[image]

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Did you try .pipe(bs.stream()); instead?

Comment: what happens if you simply delete the line:      gulp.watch('build/css/*.css').on('change', reload);  ?

Answer (score 0):

Browsersync works by injecting an asynchronous script tag `(<script async>...</script>)` right after the `<body>` tag during initial request. In order for this to work properly the `<body>` **tag must be present**.

check this out: https://browsersync.io/docs/#requirements